# ACK for packet send by socket

Tags: php, sockets, packet

I have an api, clients use get requests and I echo a json_encoded string as response.
I want to check if the string reaches its destination
without modifying the clients side.

I am thinking about opening a socket or using an open one (if not mistaken- when the user sends the GET request he opens a socket with me)
Build a packet, add the string as the data and send to port 80
How can I verify ACK for that packet? and wont the client discard this packet for security reasons?

Answer (score 0):

For securing delivery (to some degree) you should use TCP, not packets. Security is the least concern here, since you might get trouble when either side is behind a NAT. Webservers are a bit more versatile regarding connectivity than a simple socket. A GET API is by itself not very robust, in these cases the client has to retry (possibly using a unique ID that prevents double-executions).

Comment: I send the packet with TCP, not UDP- the socket is open over TCP.<br>  also, if I reach a NAT i can tell that the server is alive dont I?<br> and that my message reached the clients server.<br> I need to know the packet with the data reached the clients server

Comment: Either you mix up many things or we are far from understanding each other :) FYI: in TCP you cannot send packets, that's UDP. On TCP you are able to send data (or just open a connection) then wait for the answer. Each TCP connection may go a different route on the internet, so if you set up a separate connection, you only know that the json has reached its destination if you can contact that destination, and ask "has json#185 arrived?". This always involves some logic with the client so it is ruled out by "without modifying the client side".

Comment: NAT and the likes: being able to contact some (e.g. a NAT) server at the client does by far not indicate whether the client application had a chance to receive (not to mention process) the message. BTW in many situations the NAT server does not even belong to the client.

Comment: Yes, reaching the NAT or even getting the ACK doesn't mean the client's application got it, but it rules out one scenario. I think It is possible to create and send a packet on TCP,on an existing socket.

Comment: So if I get it right, you want to use the socket of the HTTP connection to send (or receive?) additional data. If so then I cannot figure how your idea with port 80 comes in when you say "send to port 80". You might want to spend a few words on explaining in whole sentences what you are striving for.